# How do I remove the widgets in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am referring [jQuery widgets](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets). I need to add the `Cross X` button which will remove the widget. how can I do it?

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eu2tN/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [destroy()](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-destroy) method like,

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable( "destroy" );
```

In your **code**

```
$(document).on('click','.close',function(){
     $(this).closest('.column').sortable( "destroy" ).remove();// to destroy element
     //$(this).closest('.column').sortable( "destroy" );// to destroy widget only
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/m8uPX/)

Comment: I wrote this. `$('#column1').on('click', '.portlet-header .ui-icon',function() {
      $(this).sortable("destroy");
    });`

Not working.

Comment: @user1162512 See my answer I've added `demo`  or look at http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/m8uPX/

Comment: In your current version, it removes the whole column, which can include 3/4 or many more widgets. It removes all the widgets in a column. I want to delete only the selected widget. I tried `$(this).closest('.portlet').sortable( "destroy" ).remove();` but it doesn't works.

Comment: It should be `$(this).closest('.portlet').remove();`